# Por qué falla el push a GITHUB desde Eclipse?

Tags: git, eclipse, github

Esto intentando hacer push a un repositorio que he creado en GitHub, pero me da este error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
¿Porqué no conecta y me dice que no está autorizado???

Comment: La autenticación a github cambió desde hace unos meses y ya no permite hacer algunas operaciones sólo con usuario y contraseña. Revisa.

Comment: Si Alfabravo, me vale como respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Con gusto! Para eso estamos :)